# Am trying to understand a statement in a code snippet, if somebody can help me with this

Tags: perl

I have a code snippet which has following statement.

```
$ckr = &ora_open($ldp, $rsp)
```

Comment: Hi there, if this has to do with [`Oraperl`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Oraperl), maybe the `&ora_open()`  relates to a function that takes "a login identifier" (maybe the `$ldp` in this case) and a "SQL statement to be executed" (maybe the `$rsp` in this case), [according to this documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Oraperl). The documentation also indicates that the value returned from `&ora_open()` (maybe the `$ckr` in this case) "is a statement identifier". It looks like this library is deprecated, though, so maybe this code is from an older program?

Answer (score 3):

That is a very old program. It's using [`Oraperl`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Oraperl), an old interface to an Oracle database. Now we use [`DBD::Oracle`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Oracle). It could also be DBD::Oracle in [Oraperl compatibility mode](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Oracle#CompatMode).

It's calling the `ora_open` function. `&ora_open` is an obsolete way to call functions in Perl. The `&` is no longer necessary. `&func` and `func` have subtle differences.

It's passing in the variables `$ldp` and `$rsp` and assigning the return value to `$ckr`. You can read about what those do in the documentation.

Comment: Re "*`&ora_open` is an obsolete way to call functions in Perl.*", It's almost never what someone wants --it calls the sub while ignoring its prototype-- but it's in no way obsolete.

Comment: It's kind of like a vestigial organ — no longer used for its original purpose but may have acquired secondary uses.